# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in searching for a path

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding

I am trying to write a program that takes in a matrix representing a board filled with 0s and 1s.
The goal is to find a path from the top left position to target position, using backtracking. You can only move up, down, left and right one space at a time. The code below raises

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Why is it causing the error? Is there a way to move both up, down, right and left without causing this error?

```
class Maze:
    def __init__(self, maze, target):
        self.x, self.y = target
        self.b = maze
        self.n = len(self.b)
        self.sb = [[0 for _ in range(self.n)] for _ in range(self.n)]

    def is_safe(self, row, col):
        if 0 <= row < self.n and 0 <= col < self.n and self.b[row][col] == 1:
            return True
        return False

    def find_path(self):
        move_x = [1, -1, 0, 0]
        move_y = [0, 0, 1, -1]

        if not self.find_path_rec(move_x, move_y, 0, 0):
            print("No path")
        else:
            self.print_maze()

    def find_path_rec(self, move_x, move_y, curr_x, curr_y):

        if curr_y == self.y and curr_x == self.x and self.b[self.x][self.y] == 1:
            self.sb[curr_x][curr_y] = 1
            return True

        for i in range(4):
            new_x = move_x[i] + curr_x
            new_y = move_y[i] + curr_y
            if self.is_safe(new_x, new_y):
                self.sb[new_x][new_y] = 1

                if self.find_path_rec(move_x, move_y, new_x, new_y):
                    return True

                self.sb[new_x][new_y] = 0

        return False

    def print_maze(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            for j in range(self.n):
                print(self.sb[i][j], end="")
            print()


maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: To understand recursion, need to understand recursion. By the way, do you check `self.sb`?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia maze generation algorithm page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm  has your answer

> A disadvantage of the [recursive] approach is a large depth of recursion – in the worst case, the routine may need to recur on every cell of the area being processed, which may exceed the maximum recursion stack depth in many environments.

The alternative is to a use a stack to store your path so far rather than using recursion. Appending each move to the stack, and back-tracking when you hit a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this function:

```
def is_safe(self, row, col):
    if 0 <= row < self.n and 0 <= col < self.n and self.b[row][col] == 1:
        return True
    return False
```

The condition should *include* a check that the cell has not yet been visited:

```
    if (0 <= row < self.n and 0 <= col < self.n and self.b[row][col] == 1 
                          and self.sb[row][col] == 0):
 #                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I would also advise to use names that are meaningful:

- `self.b` should better be named `self.maze`
- `self.sb` should better be named `self.visited`

Comment: I disagree with your fix.  The starting position is at a `1` and the target is verified to be a `1` so the ones are open path and the zeros are walls.  Your fix walks right into a wall.  I do agree with your variable name changes, however.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code (confused with `b` and `sb`) -- shows how difficult the code is to read by another pair of eyes if variables names are badly chosen ;) I will update in a minute.

Comment: Updated my answer. The old condition is back, but I added what I intended to add.

Comment: Do you have any feed back?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in this line:

```
if self.is_safe(new_x, new_y):
```

which should be:

```
if self.is_safe(new_x, new_y) and self.sb[new_x][new_y] == 0:
```

That is, don't *revisit* positions as you'll get into a circular motion and thus recursive stack overflow.  Below is my rework of your code in my own thinking about your problem:

```
COL, ROW = (0, 1)

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, maze, target):
        self.target = target
        self.maze = maze
        self.visited = set()

    def is_safe(self, position):
        col, row = position
        return 0 <= row < len(self.maze) and 0 <= col < len(self.maze[row]) and self.maze[row][col] == 1

    def find_path(self):
        start = (0, 0)
        moves = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

        self.visited.add(start)

        return self.find_path_recursive(moves, start)

    def find_path_recursive(self, moves, current):

        if current == self.target and self.maze[self.target[ROW]][self.target[COL]] == 1:
            return True

        for move in moves:
            new = move[COL] + current[COL], move[ROW] + current[ROW]

            if self.is_safe(new) and new not in self.visited:
                self.visited.add(new)

                if self.find_path_recursive(moves, new):
                    return True

                self.visited.remove(new)

        return False

    def print_maze(self):
        for row in range(len(self.maze)):
            for col in range(len(self.maze[row])):
                print(1 if (col, row) in self.visited else 0, end="")
            print()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    maze = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1]
    ]

    game = Maze(maze, (3, 3))

    if game.find_path():
        game.print_maze()
    else:
        print("No path")
```

My sense of coordinates my be different than yours, so take that into account when evaluating results.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1111
0001
0001
0001
>
```

If we move the target to `(1, 3)`, then we get:

```
> python3 test.py
1100
1100
1000
1100
>
```

I also changed your logic to potentially handle rectangular mazes instead of just square ones.